# Build dependencies with webpack from node_modules src

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

So I have code that imports a package I installed with `npm install --save dependency` like so:

```
import myDep from dependency
```

In the dependency I am using are two versions, a debug and a minified version. I can see a huge difference when manually fiddeling with the package.json in the node_modules/dependency folder. So wepback is NOT compiling it from source but taking the build file.

I want to tell webpack that it should compile this dependency from it's source rather then mangeling just the prebuilt file into the bundle.

Is there any way to tell webpack this?